# PowerShell alias-assignment factory

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I need to support multiple database instances, so I created a 'factory' function to assign an alias (`Invoke-DbCmd`) to the desired function/cmdlet:

MySql (dummy):

```
function Invoke-MySqlCmd {
    param(
        [string]$Query
    )
    write-debug "Invoke-MySqlCmd"

    # add implementation
}
```

Oracle (dummy):

```
function Invoke-OracleCmd {
    param(
        [string]$Query
    )
    write-host "Invoke-OracleCmd"

    # add implementation
}
```

'Factory' function:

```
function Register-DbCommand {

    param(
        [ValidateSet('com.oracle','com.microsoft','org.mysql')]
        [string]$Namespace
    )

    # remove existing assignment
    Remove-Item alias:\Invoke-DbCmd -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    $cmd = $null

    switch ($Namespace) {
        com.microsoft { 
            write-debug "Invoke-SqlCmd"
            $cmd = Get-Command Invoke-SqlCmd
        } 
        com.oracle { 
            write-debug "Invoke-OracleCmd"
            $cmd = Get-Item Function:Invoke-OracleCmd
        } 
        org.mysql {
            write-debug "Invoke-MySqlCmd"
            $cmd = Get-Item Function:Invoke-MySqlCmd
        }
    }

    # return reference to new alias
    Set-Alias -Name Invoke-DbCmd -Value $cmd -PassThru

}
```

While it appears that the alias is created:

```
PS> register-dbcommand -Namespace 'com.oracle'
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           Invoke-DbCmd
```

The alias isn't listed:

```
PS> get-alias | ? {$_.Definition -like 'Invoke*'} | select displayname

DisplayName
-----------
?? -> Invoke-NullCoalescing
curl -> Invoke-WebRequest
icm -> Invoke-Command
iex -> Invoke-Expression
ihy -> Invoke-History
ii -> Invoke-Item
irm -> Invoke-RestMethod
iwmi -> Invoke-WmiMethod
iwr -> Invoke-WebRequest
pester -> Invoke-Pester
psake -> Invoke-psake
r -> Invoke-History
wget -> Invoke-WebRequest
```

Attempts to use the alias generate an exception:

```
PS> invoke-dbcmd
invoke-dbcmd : The term 'invoke-dbcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ invoke-dbcmd
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (invoke-dbcmd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting that it appears to work, but you should probably be using `New-Alias` since you're removing it first. You could add on `-Force` and then not remove the existing one too.

Based on your comments, the above seems unrelated, by try setting it in the global scope with `New-Alias -Scope Global`.

Comment: Disabled the `Remove-Item` line.  Changed the last line to `New-Alias -Name Invoke-DbCmd -Value $cmd -Force -PassThru`.  Same behavior.

Comment: `-Scope Global` did the trick.  I also enabled my original syntax elements.